# Prestashop 1.7: Need to add margin product in the step 3 (price) on the backend product page

Tags: prestashop

I searched all over the web and here.
I can't find the solution. I simply need to add the branch variable which corresponds to the sale price excluding VAT and the variable which corresponds to the purchase price
Because I have to display the margin ht and do the margin calculation in %.
Do you know please?

Best regard.

I can't find price variables for twig files (product in admin)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to edit this part:

[image: Summary section from Pricing tab]

Which is under `Product > Pricing` in the BO.

The twig template associated to this section is the `price_summary_widget` which is defined in this template:

`src/PrestaShopBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Sell/Catalog/Product/FormTheme/product.html.twig`

```
{% block price_summary_widget %}
  <div {{ block('widget_attributes') }}>
    <div class="price-summary-block">
      <div class="price-summary-value price-tax-excluded-value"></div>
      <div class="price-summary-value price-tax-included-value"></div>
      <div class="price-summary-value unit-price-value"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price-summary-block">
      <div class="price-summary-value margin-value"></div>
      <div class="price-summary-value margin-rate-value"></div>
      <div class="price-summary-value wholesale-price-value"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see there are no default value since they're fetched using a JS script located in `/<admin_folder>/themes/new-theme/public/product_edit.bundle.js?<ps_version>`.

Files included in this bundle can be found in `/<admin_folder>/themes/new-theme/js/pages/product/edit`. The one interesting in your case is `price-summary.ts`.

I don't recommend to edit directly these files because they are part of PrestaShop's core.

However you can create a [module](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/creation/) and then extend the files you need.

You can find here a guide on how to extend an Admin template : [Overriding Back office views](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/concepts/templating/admin-views/#override-the-template-in-the-module-a-simple-hello-world)

Here you could for example override the `javascripts` block to add your own script :

```
{% extends '@!PrestaShop/Admin/Sell/Catalog/Product/edit.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
  {{ parent() }}

  <script src="{{ asset('custom-script') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

It is possible to create you own script mainly based on PrestaShop's bundle (by recreating the bundle and replacing the `price-summary.ts` with your own) but it will require to compile your core using webpack.

You can base its configuration on this one `<admin_folder>/themes/new-theme/.webpack/common.js` and/or this one `modules/ps_linklist/views/webpack.config.js`.